# H2 not using indexes for ORDER BY?

Tags: h2

H2 does not seem to make use of INDEXes for ORDER BY. I have a Table "CITY" holding the following fields:

- CITY_ID --> PK INDEX (int)
- COUNTRY_CODE --> 2 chars
- CITY_NAME --> string
- and some other fields

on which is defined an INDEX (COUNTRY_CODE, CITY_NAME).

When applying the query

```
SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE COUNTRY_CODE='CH' ORDER BY CITY_NAME
```

it seems that H2 uses the INDEX only on COUNTRY_CODE but does not use the second part of the INDEX to order by CITY_NAME. I use the latest version of H2 but same problem in older versions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Now I don't know H2, but my logic says that the index is "sorted" by `country_code` first, ***then*** `city_name`.

Comment: Does it work if you use `SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE COUNTRY_CODE='CH' ORDER BY COUNTRY_CODE, CITY_NAME`? I know it's redundant, but I guess the database is not smart enough to figure it out otherwise...

Comment: September 2019. Index for ORDER BY is still left unused.